# Notepad++ regex search 2 conditions

Tags: regex, notepad++

I trying to use this

```
(?=<[^<>]+>)(?=.*<[^<>]+src=(.*?).?+alt=(.*?).?+width=.*?>).*
```

with this string

```
<img class=""aligncenter  wp-image-27545"" src=""http://www.obrasenmiciudad.df.gob.mx/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Imagen2-150x113.png"" alt="""" width=""398"" height=""279"" />     5645 4684 9849 8498 498 4984 9846541513213
```

But I find the whole string and I need to find the string without the numbers after >, like this

```
<img class=""aligncenter  wp-image-27545"" src=""http://www.obrasenmiciudad.df.gob.mx/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Imagen2-150x113.png"" alt="""" width=""398"" height=""279"" />
```

Comment: Then why do you have `.*` at the end of the regex?! If you want to parse XML/HTML, *use an proper parser*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you are exactly trying to do, but you don't need all of these lookaheads that are useless. Instead of using a lot of `.*` that are too permissive and will produce a lot of backtracking, you should use character classes too limit subpatterns match:

```
<img[^>]*?\ssrc=([^>\s]*+)[^>]*?\salt=(""[^"]*"")[^>]*>
```

Comment: It works, but now i have a problem with newlines, if don´t find `>` search in next line, how can avoid search in the next line?

Answer (score 1):

The expression you presented has two non consuming validation expressions (the bits starting ?=). It is the bit at the end that will match & consume the bit you want.
so this might work for you

```
(?=<[^<>]+>)(?=.*<[^<>]+src=(.*?).?+alt=(.*?).?+width=.*>)(.*\/>)
```